# Text not centering in my li

Tags: html, css, alignment

[**Demo link**](http://alpha.whoat.net/mobile_request)

Not sure why my text in the 2nd list isn't getting centered.

[image]

**The HTML**

```
<div id="the_target">
    <ul>
        <li>Stephen Marston</li>
        <li>Account Exectutive</li>
        <li>The Company</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**SASS:**

```
section {
    #the_requestor {
        margin-top: 40px;
        ul { margin-top: 10px; }
        ul li {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: $px20;
        }
        li:first-child {
            font-family: LatoBold;
            font-size: $px30;
            background: cyan;
        }
    }
    #the_target {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 40px;
        ul { margin-top: 10px; }
        ul li {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: $px20;
        }
        li:first-child{
            font-family: LatoBold;
            font-size: $px30;
            background: cyan;
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what could be forcing Stephen Marston to not center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an element being floated in `#mobile-action-area` that is interfering.  You need to clear this float.  There are a variety of ways to do it.  Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#mobile-action-area` fixes it.  You may also try:

```
#mobile-action-area:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Or add "display:inline-block;" to this style: "body#mobile-request .container #mobile-action-area"

Comment: Ah that was it! I had to hack my `#mobile-deny-request` because the button was too low for some reason. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to clear the float before #the_target

```
   #the_target {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 40px;
            clear:both;
    }
```